# Magento 2.3.4?How to change the cronjob frequency?

Tags: magento2.3

I need to change the cronjob frequency for amazon_payments_process_queued_refunds and bulk_cleanup from 5 to 15 mins. Please let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following way:

1. Create a module where the sequence should be **Amazon_Payment**. E.g:

```
    <module name="Vendor_AmzPayment">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Amazon_Payment"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
```

2. Create crontab.xml. Modify schedule tag. E.g:

```
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
        <group id="default">
            <job name="amazon_payments_process_queued_refunds" instance="Amazon\Payment\Cron\ProcessAmazonRefunds" method="execute">
                <schedule>*/15 * * * *</schedule>
            </job>
        </group>
    </config>
```

Comment: Thanks Sohel, I got about 13 such jobs to adjust their schedules. All of them are different jobs like bulk_cleanup and consummers_runner. Do I need to create module for each of them?

Comment: Hi @CodeForGood, No but make sure your custom module loaded last.

Comment: I got a custom module in my project. Please let me know what you meant by custom module loaded last.

Comment: Please guide me a little on how to do this.